# which uitextfield delegate will be called on entering value

Tags: uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Which delegate will be called on entering the value in UITextfield and before leaving the focus of that that textbox. i want  to compare the value of textfiled with other string before entering the focus. and clear the textbox if value does not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

This asks the delegate if editing should begin in the specified text field. You can pass the UITextField object as an argument.

This will be called just when the focus is directed to the UITextField object.

Before you leave the focus, i.e. end editing, the following delegate method gets called:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

This asks the delegate if editing should stop in the specified text field. In your case, when you lose the focus from the UITextField object.

In the implementation of the first delegate method mentioned, you can actually write the code for comparing the text in the UITextField and the string with which you want to compare with.

Thus, you can then decide whether you have to clear the text in the UITextField, or retain it.